# Why is my last AND condition returning false in the if statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I have an array as follows:

```
var temp = ["5","5","5","5"];
```

And here is the If condition:

```
if((temp[0] == temp[1]) && (temp[1] == temp[2]) && (temp[2] == temp[3])){
   square++;
}
```

Why is my last condition `temp[2] == temp[3]` returning `false`?

When I check the values of both these indexes in the console, they show equal, but the condition itself returns `false`.

Any ideas?

Comment: because you have a single quote at index three instead of a double quote

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo. The arrays are being dynamically generated. Corrected the question.

Comment: *Why is my last condition temp[2] == temp[3] returning false?* - no, it doesn't.

Comment: Maybe print temp0, temp1, temp2 and temp3....

Comment: The condition for your array is true and the if works as intended. Please post reproducible code.

Comment: Its working right.

Comment: ya it doesn't return false... .

Comment: The array is being generated dynamically via a text file. I wish I could provide screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working as it should. However, to check if all elements in your array are equal, simply use .every

```js
var temp = ["5","5","5","5"];

if (temp.every((e,i,arr) => e === arr[0])) {
 alert("all the same");
}
```

or using a es6 Set

```js
var temp = ["5","5","5","5"];
if (new Set(temp).size === 1) alert("all the same");
```

Comment: In my case, even this returns false :( I like your answer though.

Comment: If that returns false, your values aren't the same. Check for hidden/invisible characters or spaces. @VinodBhavnani

Answer (score 0):

It can return false if `temp[3]` does not exist. So if you are saying arrays are generated dynamically there is a possibility you are checking if your last value equals value that doesn't exist.

I mean if your `array.length = 4` and you are manually testing if `temp[3] == temp[4]`

Also check values for `NaN` as `NaN == NaN` returns `false`